# Object is of type 'unknown' on catch block

Tags: typescript, axios, try-catch

I'm trying to create an axios abstraction, but I'm getting this error on catch block.

**Object is of type 'unknown'.**

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { injectable } from "inversify";
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse, IHttp } from "../../interfaces/Ihttp";

@injectable()
export class AxiosHttpClient implements IHttp {
  async request(params: HttpRequest): Promise<HttpResponse> {
    let axiosResponse: AxiosResponse;

    try {
      axiosResponse = await axios.request({
        url: params.url,
        method: params.method,
        data: params.body,
        headers: params.headers,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      axiosResponse = error.response;
    }

    return {
      statusCode: axiosResponse.status,
      data: axiosResponse.data,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#use-unknown-catch-variables ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem putting the `useUnknownInCatchVariables` option to false in tsconfig.json